How to fix MP4 file whose recording was terminated by TERM signal?
I want to be able to listen to the content already recorded. The file contains Opus stream in MP4 container and it is recorded from Internet using ffmpeg (4.4.2).
$ ffprobe -hide_banner file.m4a
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xa9000800] moov atom not found
file.m4a: Invalid data found when processing input


ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -vn audio.wav && ffmpeg -i audio.wav audio.m4a That should recover the audio.  Video must be re-encoded to fix a missing moov.

@JayCravens The first command fails with the aforementioned error.

Ouch.  It's expected though.  Will it re-encode?  Try: ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -crf 10 -preset ultrafast -shortest -movflags +faststart re-encode.mkv

I succeeded making my files playable by using https://github.com/anthwlock/untrunc
With that you probably need a working file from the same source besides the broken file.
I followed instructions in the README: built the tool "With system libraries" and used the tool like instructed. You get help about the options by untrunc  -h, but you might not need any options. The tool is for video, but seems to work for pure audio files, too.

Explaining HOW you used this tool in order to solve the problem will make this an answer. Currently, this is only a comment. Please EDIT this post to make it a full answer.
